# Error while copying content to a stream. IFormFile read Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to read Data from `xsls` to update my database.
Note: this code is working fine in my local machine .the error comes up only when I publish to server.

the below is the error

```
{error: "Error while copying content to a stream.",…}
error
: 
"Error while copying content to a stream."
exceptionType
: 
"System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException"
innerException
: 
"Cannot access a disposed object.\r\nObject name: 'System.Net.Http.StreamContent'."
stackTrace
: 
"   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CheckDisposed()\r\n
```

this my code block

```
 [RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 52428800, ValueLengthLimit = 52428800)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ImportSheet([FromForm] IFormFile uploadedFile)
        {
            var isClean = await _antimalwareScanService.PostSingleFileResponseAsync(uploadedFile);
            if (isClean)
            {
      
                if ( uploadedFile is null)
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(uploadedFile.FileName))
                {
                    using var stream = uploadedFile.OpenReadStream();
                    //using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                    //await stream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                     using  ExcelPackage excel = new(stream);
                    ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;

                    ExcelWorkbook workbook = excel.Workbook;

                    ExcelWorksheets worksheets = workbook.Worksheets;
                    var psWorksheets = worksheets.FirstOrDefault(x =>    x.Name.ToLower().Contains("prof services"));
                    if (psWorksheets != null)
                    {
                         await _fileViewModelService.UploadProfServicesFile(psWorksheets);
                    }
                    stream.Dispose();
                }
            }

            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can remove [FromForm] as .net core knows where to get its data from. I have also given you details on how to get it as stream then as byteArray and finally as Base64. You can use whatever works for you.

```
    [HttpPost("File")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ImportSheet(IFormFile uploadedFile)
    {
        if (uploadedFile.Length > 0)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await uploadedFile.CopyToAsync(ms);
                var fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
                string s = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
            }
        }
        return Ok();
    }
```